# How to validate modified Firebase token

Tags: c#, .net, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm working on the backend of an app in C# .NET that works with a JWT to access to some endpoints. Now I've added compatibility with the Firebase JWT tokens and they work fine.

The thing is the frontend is modifying this token to add some properties, such as the role of the user, but then I can't validate the token since it gives me the following error:

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was
> not found", Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The
> signature key was not found"

I'm not sure how to approach the issue, since I still don't know much about firebase JWT.

What would be the right way to make it work?

Comment: If the frontend modifies the token it invalidates the signature. That's the basic principle of signed tokens. Why do you want to validate something invalid?

Comment: Okay, so what would be the right way to add the new properties to it?

Comment: whatever you want to add, it has to be added by the issuer of the token and before it is signed. But that's a [different question](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase%5D%5Bjwt%5Dadd+claims)

Answer (score 1):

> the frontend is modifying this token to add some properties, such as the role of the user

That seems like a security risk. If the front-end code sets the role of the user, any user can claim any role for themselves.

The normal approach for this is to [set custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#set_and_validate_custom_user_claims_via_the_admin_sdk) in a trusted environment, which then also ensures the token gets properly signed in that environment.